# How to identify customers and suppliers on sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello Stack Overflow community! I am hoping someone can help pass along some advice on if this query looks ok and if there could be any improvements, and also how I can go about identifying whether a row is a customer or supplier. I've posted my code below, thanks in advance for the help!

*A representative from Northwind Traders will be in Germany. Management would like her to visit all German suppliers and customers while she is there. Provide a list of all suppliers and customers in Germany, including contacts and addresses. Designate on the report whether the company listed is a customer or a supplier.*

```
select *  
from
  Suppliers s
  inner join Products p
    on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
  inner join OrderDetails od
    on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
  inner join Orders o
    on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
  inner join Customers c
   on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
where
  (s.Country = 'Germany') 
  and (c.Country = 'Germany')
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a small sample from the necessary tables, a sample of what your current query outputs, and most importantly a sample of what the output _should_ look like?  Your current query looks to me as though it produces a list of orders with supplier and customer for each row, not a list of suppliers and customers each as their _own_ separate rows as I understand the question to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve in only one Select and without any other manipulation out of the SQL, You can obtain the columns of both Suppliers and Customers using UNION:

```
select 'Supplier' partnerType, s.name, s.contact, s.address 
from Suppliers s inner join Products p on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
                 inner join OrderDetails od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
                 inner join Orders o on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
where 
 (s.Country = 'Germany')
Union
Select 'Customer' partnerType, c.name, c.contact, c.address 
from Suppliers s inner join Products p on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
                 inner join OrderDetails od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
                 inner join Orders o on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
                 inner join Customers c on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
where 
 (c.Country = 'Germany')
```

To identify if is a supplier or a customer, only use column partnerType.

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch Supplier and customer details separately and merge using the `UNION ALL`. Thing is, you need to use the same column alias names in both the queries and introduce new column `TYPE` with either **SUPPLIER** or **CUSTOMER** appropriately as shown in the below structure,

```
SELECT SUPPLIERS.NAME AS NAME
    ..
    ..
    , 'SUPPLIER' AS TYPE 
FROM SUPPLIERS 
WHERE COUNTRY = 'Germany'
UNION ALL
SELECT CUSTOMERS.NAME AS NAME
    ..
    ..
    , 'CUSTOMER' AS TYPE
FROM CUSTOMERS  
WHERE COUNTRY = 'Germany'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
SELECT CustomerID AS ID,
       Customers.Contact AS Contact,
       Customers.Address AS Address,
       "Customer" AS Type
FROM Customers
WHERE Customers.Country = "Germany"
UNION
SELECT SupplierID,
       Suppliers.Contact,
       Suppliers.Address,
       "Supplier"
FROM Suppliers
WHERE Suppliers.Country = "Germany";
```

I wasn't sure if Contact or Address were one field or many.  Feel free to adjust to suit the structure of your tables.

I suggest studying the differences between `JOIN` and `UNION`.  `UNION` is effective here because the details from the two tables have the same format.